# java.lang.StackOverflowError in MergeSort recursive

Tags: java, sorting

I try to debug a 10 size list.
`ascendingSort(list, start, partition)` works good.
 but after recursing `ascendingSort(list, start, partition)` , `ascendingSort(list, partition, end)` failed, its start, end is not 5 10, but just 0 1.

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void ascendingSort(List<T> list) {
    ascendingSort(list, 0, list.size());
}

private <T extends Comparable<T>> void ascendingSort
        (List<T> list, int start, int end) {
    if (start == end) {
        return;
    }
    int partition = (start + end) >> 1;
    ascendingSort(list, start, partition);
    ascendingSort(list, partition, end);
    merge(list, start, partition, end);
}

private <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge
        (List<T> list, int start, int partition, int end) {
    List<T> leftList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<T> rightList = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.copy(leftList, list.subList(start, partition));
    Collections.copy(rightList, list.subList(partition, end));
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (int k = start; k < end; k ++) {
        T leftElement = leftList.get(i);
        T rightElement = rightList.get(j);
        if (leftElement.compareTo(rightElement) > 0) {
            list.set(k, rightElement);
            j++;
        } else {
            list.set(k, leftElement);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This 0,1 you are checking is at the point when the recursive call of first ascendingSort is finished with parameters as list,0,1.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in the code:

```
if (start == end) {
    return;
}
```

is incorrect, you should use the next piece of code instead:

```
if (end - start < 2) {
    return;
}
```

That was the reason for StackOverflowException. Try to debug your code and see why it happens.

Next, `Collections.copy(leftList, list.subList(start, partition));` doesn't work for empty collections (`leftList` is empty on a moment of creation), I'd reccomend to pass sublist as parameter to constructor:

```
List<T> leftList = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(start, partition));
List<T> rightList = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(partition, end));
```

After this, you'll have an exception `IndexOutOfBoundException`, because there is no check for list size in merge loop. Please, check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-sort) for merge sort implementation for arrays and do same for lists.